# Is putting the env file at the root of my project folder makes it invisible on the client side?

Tags: security, environment-variables, sensitive-data

As the title says + is this approach enough to protect the sensitive data?

Or should I store the sensitive data on a 3rd party service?
How to deal with data protection?!

Comment: The answer here depends on your server setup, and the sensitivity of the data. Nuclear launch codes? You'll probably want something more secure.

Comment: So putting the sensitive data on an env file on the root of the project's folder not enough!

Comment: No, that's not an accurate summary of what I said. It *may* be enough; security here is partially on *you*.

Comment: I got you, another question, is there any way to access the .env file on the client side?

Comment: Again, it depends. It's entirely possible for you to misconfigure things. I've seen folks point the webserver at the wrong folder, I've seen folks output the `.env` into the frontend HTML. You need to understand what you're doing, but that's not unique to `.env` files.